# Animation separating in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiimageview, core-animation

I got an app with a simple `UIView`. There is a matrix NxN of `UIImageViews` on this `UIview`.

I wanna turn each UIImageView. But one by one. I tried this code:

```
for (int k=0; k<kol; k++)
        for (int l=0; l<kol; l++)
        {
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
                int posTo = pole[k][l].position ;
                pole[k][l].position++;
                if (posTo == 4) {posTo=0; pole[k][l].position=1;}
                pole[k][l].imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633*posTo);
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
```

But all images rotate in the same time.

How should i separate this animation?

UPD

Right now i use this code for more complicated animation:

```
-(void) turnAllPole
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:delay];
    for (int k=0; k<kol; k++)
        for (int l=0; l<kol; l++)
        {
            if (poleBeforeTurn[k][l] == 1)
            {
                int posTo = pole[k][l].position ;
                pole[k][l].position++;
                if (posTo == 4) {posTo=0; pole[k][l].position=1;}
                pole[k][l].imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633*posTo);
           }    
        }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    delay += 0.3;
}
```

that's for synchronized rotation of some matrix' parts (where `poleBeforeTurn[k][l] == 1`). But this code firstly rotate all parts in one time (like if i use in loops only `pole[k][l].imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633*posTo);` without animation) and after that implement animation.

How should i avoid first rotation and implement only animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set a delay to each of the UIImageView animations:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelay:delay];
```

If you increment the duration of the delay after every loop you should get the desired effect.

Comment: [UIView setAnimationDelay:delay]; dont lead to dalay between animation, but only before all animation

Comment: Yes, that's why you increment the delay after each loop (e.g. delay += 0.2). So every Animation has a different delay. I don't have time to try that, but I think that should work.

Answer (score 2):

the first parameter of `beginAnimations:context:` is an animationID. You can use it to group (or in your case ungroup) animations.

Try to use a different animationID for each of your objects

```
float delay = 0;
for (int k=0; k<kol; k++)
    for (int l=0; l<kol; l++)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"anim_%d_d", k, l] context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:delay];
        /* animate */
        delay += 0.05;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was unsure that this works so I just tried it and it turns out that you don't need an animationID if you use a different delay for each view

Answer (score 0):

Try NSTimer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003747

Write a method for cell's animation (cell's coords will be params) and put a timer between different calls

Comment: also sleep(1); and wait(1); dont work. i wait for NxN seconds and then i see animation of all images